# Proper context for wp_remote_post()

Tags: http-api, contextual-help

I would like to use [wp_remote_post()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post) within a function to send an HTTP Post Request to a php script inside a plug-in.

I'm successfully posting to the plug-in script, but having trouble with the *context* of the request.

In ***functions.php***:

```
function post_to_plugin($name, $email) {
  $plugin_url = plugins_url( '/my-plugin/db-insert.php' );
  $form = array( 'name' => $name, 'email' => $email );
  $result = wp_remote_post( 
    $plugin_url, 
    array(
      'body' => $form
    ) 
  );
}
```

Example ***/my-plugin/db-insert.php***:

```
if (preg_match('#' . basename(__FILE__) . '#', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])) { die('You are not allowed to call this page directly.'); }

if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->insert( 
    'table', 
     array ( 
      'name' => $_POST['name'], 
      'email' => $_POST['email'] 
     )
  );
}
```

My post request gets stopped by the first line in the *db-insert.php*. I can remove this line, which can't be a good solution. But then `insert` still fails because *db-insert.php* can't find the `global $wpdb`. Is it possible to make this post request in the proper context of wordpress / the plugin script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't post directly to your plugin file - WordPress won't be loaded, and you shouldn't load it manually.

Use the AJAX API and an action hook to handle it (note it doesn't need to be an *actual* AJAX request):

```
function wpse_180814_post_to_plugin( $name, $email ) {
    $result = wp_remote_post( 
        admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 
        array(
            'body' => array(
                'action' => 'wpse_180814_action',
                'name'   => $name,
                'email'  => $email,
            ),
        ) 
    );
}

function wpse_180814_action() {
    if ( isset( $_POST['name'], $_POST['email'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->insert( 
            'table', 
            array ( 
                'name' => $_POST['name'], 
                'email' => $_POST['email'] 
            )
        );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpse_180814_action', 'wpse_180814_action' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpse_180814_action', 'wpse_180814_action' );
```